# How to find the accurate determinant of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I'm solving the determinant of this matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\
 2& 2 &5\\ 3& 5& 1\end{bmatrix}$. I got two different answers by Gaussian Elimination. What's wrong with the second path?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br0lA.jpg)

Comment: Here is what I tried: the second path cannot be expressed as product of elementary matrix. specifically, elementary matrix of the form adding scalar product of a row to another. What say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Computing_determinants), the third rule says "Adding to one row a scalar multiple of another does not change the determinant." So adding half of row two to the third row will not change the determinant. But first multiplying row 3 by a factor of $2$ will double the determinant (rule 2). Subtracting now row 2 will not change the determinant anymore, but it will be doubled at the previous step. So the only operation you are allowed to do on some row $n$ is $$r_n\to r_n+\sum_{m\ne n}c_m r_m$$

Answer (score 0):

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 2 & 5 \\ 
3 & 5 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 15 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
3 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 15 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 2 & 5 \\ 
3 & 5 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

..........